# Same values on rand() function wit for loop - PHP

Tags: php, random

I'm trying to generate 10 different number with rand() function using for loop. My codes:

```
    <?php

$rand = rand();

for ($i=1 ; $i<=10 ; $i++){
    echo $rand."\n";
}
?>
```

But when I run my code output something like that:

```
4481
4481
4481
4481
4481
4481
4481
4481
4481
4481
```

All 10 values are same, but I want to get all of them different.

In C, there is a **srand(time(NULL))** code to prevent from this, what is the alternative solution in PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `echo rand()."\n";`

Comment: You are printing the same variable, you need to call the function instead

Comment: I get it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @ofarukcaki in first line $rand = rand(); you assigned a single number which is generated by rand() in that time, this means that you assigned a fix number not a rand() function in $rand variable

so try below one

```
<?php
//$rand = rand(); $rand assigned a number which will be fixed for the below lines of code, instead of using $rand use direct rand() in below loop which we will generate 10 different numbers randomly
    for ($i=1 ; $i<=10 ; $i++){
        echo rand()."<br>";;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for ($i=1 ; $i<=10 ; $i++){
    echo rand()."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
$min=1111;
$max=9999;    
for ($i=1 ; $i<=10 ; $i++)
{
    echo rand($min,$max);
    echo "<BR>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$string1 = str_shuffle('1234567890');
$random1 = substr($string1,0,10);
echo $random1;
```